# How to merge/add variable in angular

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Below is my user object. Once i submit form i am getting values for it along with priPhone , mobilePhone.

```
   this.user = {
        isActive: 1,
        contactDetails: {
            name: { }
        },
     };
   } 

mobilePhone:any={phoneNumber: '',type:'Mobile'}; 
primaryPhone:any={phoneNumber: '',type:'Primary'};
```

I have to set mobilePhone, primaryPhone details to User Object.
So that i want final object like this.

```
this.user = {
        isActive: 1,
        contactDetails: {
            name: { }
        },
        phoneNumbers: [{
            phoneNumber: '',
            type: 'Primary'
        }, {
            phoneNumber: '',
            type: 'Mobile'
        }]
     };
```

How to do it ?

Comment: `this.user.phoneNumbers = [mobilePhone, primaryPhone];`

Answer (score 2):

This should work in javascript.

```
this.user.phoneNumbers = [];
this.user.phoneNumbers.push(mobilePhone);
this.user.phoneNumbers.push(primaryPhone);
```

or simply

```
this.user.phoneNumbers = [mobilePhone, primaryPhone];
```

Comment: mobileType:any={'type':'MOBILE'}; 
        this.user.contactDetails.phoneNumbers = [];
        this.user.contactDetails.phoneNumbers.push(this.mobileType);
        this.user.contactDetails.phoneNumbers[0].phoneNumber = this.mobilePhone;  it is not working. what is wrong in it ?